# Free memory for IHTMLDocument2

Tags: delphi, ihtmldocument2

I'm using IHTMLDocument2 as this:

```
var
  doc: OleVariant;

doc:= coHTMLDocument.Create as IHTMLDocument2;
doc:= CreateComObject(Class_HTMLDOcument) as IHTMLDocument2;
doc.write(html);
doc.close;
(...)
```

How should I dispose of "doc" properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to do anything to dispose of it, if `doc` is a local variable (within a procedure or function). `IHTMLDocument2` is an interface and is reference counted; the compiler will make sure it's released when it goes out of scope.

If it's not a local variable, you can simply set it to `null` or `Unassigned`, as in `doc := Unassigned;` which will decrement the reference count.

Comment: But nil will raise a compiler error, since doc is OleVariant. Using "unassigned" works as well?

Comment: `doc := nil` would work if `doc` were declared as `IHTMLDocument2`, but because it is declared as `OleVariant`, use `doc := Unassigned` or `doc := Null` instead.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: both `Unassigned` and `Null` will work to release the document.

Comment: @MiguelE: Yes. I missed (as Remy pointed out) that the variable was declared as OleVariant instead of `IHTMLDocument2`. Corrected, and thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Remy: Thanks. I missed the OleVariant rather than IHHTMLDocument2 in the variable declaration (it wasn't there when I was writing my answer, and I didn't catch it when the edit was made by the OP right after I posted my answer). I've made the correction - thanks for catching it.

Comment: @Remy I was wrong. `Null` has a different meaning. `Unassigned` is correct. I deleted my bogus comment.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: different meaning, but the end effect is the same. Assigning *any* new value to the `OleVariant` will release the interface it is currently holding.